# Need to display data from one column into the same column on a separate row which the identifier is the same

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the following example table

| ID | StartDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 05/12/2007 |
| 1 | 31/05/2010 |

I need it so that there is only one row per ID with the earliest start date as follows:

| ID | StartDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 05/12/2007 |

Is there a way to do this in mySQL?

Many Thanks

Comment: Your dates are not in mysql format what dataype is startdate?

Comment: Hi the data type is Date. i used the Format function to get the date looking this way. Thanks

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_min

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply do this, first arrange The items date wise and then apply the group by clause.

query may be:

`` SELECT FROM `TABLE` GROUP BY `ID` ORDER BY `StartDate`; ``

First group by then order by.

Comment: Another method:

Comment: ``` SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `TABLE` ORDER BY StartDate ASC) AS sub GROUP BY `ID`; ```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options - e.g. null left joins - but the simplest approach is probably something like this (and I'm assuming a unique column of 'UID'):

```
select t1.id, t1.startdate from myTable as t1
join myTable as t2 on t2.uid = (select uid from myTable where id = t1.id order by 
startdate limit 1)
where t1.uid = t2.uid;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(StartDate)
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY ID
```